# JreCompat is available in 2 locations which one is correct and how to fix this please?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, mvn-repo

```
The method's class, org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat, is available from the following locations:

jar:file: .m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/9.0.13/tomcat-util-9.0.13.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/compat/JreCompat.class
jar:file: .m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.41/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/compat/JreCompat.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat: file: .m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/9.0.13/tomcat-util-9.0.13.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat

Comment: the first one..

Comment: Both jar's have their applications. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66187683/edit) your question and explain what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to embed Tomcat in your application or are you writing a web application to be run inside of Tomcat?